# Unable to run a simple example -- "use of unstable library feature 'rustc_private': ....."

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use simplelog.rs in my Rust application. The hello world example

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate log;
extern crate simplelog;

// ..........
CombinedLogger::init(vec![
    TermLogger::new(LogLevelFilter::Warn, simplelog::Config::default()).unwrap(),
    WriteLogger::new(LogLevelFilter::Info, simplelog::Config::default(), File::create("log.log").unwrap())]).unwrap();
```

results into this:

```
error: use of unstable library feature 'rustc_private': this crate is being loaded from the sysroot, an unstable location; did you mean to load this crate from crates.io via `Cargo.toml` instead? (see issue #27812)
 --> src/main.rs:9:1
  |
9 | extern crate log;
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

How to fix it?

From the discussion of [#27812](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27812) it's still unclear what to do about it.

Comment: How are you running this?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing `log = "version"` entry in `Cargo.toml` `[dependencies]`.

Because of that Cargo doesn't give Rust a `log` crate to load with `extern crate log`, and Rust keeps looking for it deeper, finding some internal one.